# How to cope with "the application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect" error in vmware?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vmware, side-by-side

When I try to open released .exe file (which I wrote in Visual Studio 2008) in VMWare Workstation 6.5 with Windows Server 2008 32bit OS, got "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect." error all time even if the code is;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

  printf ("HELLO\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Is anyone faced that king of problem or does know how to cope with it?

Comment: Have you installed the correct runtime redistributable on the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to deploy the [runtime support DLLs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en) or copied the Debug build of your program.  For a small program like this without DLLs that export C++ classes or pointers it is better to link the static version of the CRT.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, /MTd.  Repeat for the Release configuration, now choose /MT.

Comment: Thanks Hans it worked for that code but for my real project it gave same error. My real project includes inline-assembler. Do you have any idea if it requires further solution?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with VMWare -- it has to do with not having the correct side-by-side assemblies for the C runtime installed.  You need to know which ones you require, and then install the runtime.  You can also control it with a manifest.

There is some info here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly

One easy way (for C/C++ programs) to get around this is to change to linking to the C-runtime statically.  Go to your project properties, then Code Generation, and choose static linking for the C Runtime.  Then you won't have a dependency on the runtime dlls.  All libraries you might be using need to be linked this way for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I generally get this error if the C/C++ runtime that the program was built with was not installed in the VM. You can download the CRT for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 at [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2). Make sure to download the correct version of the CRT based on the versions of Visual Studio used to build the app.

Comment: Is it for Visual Studio or Wİndows to be installed? If it is for windows, I need to install it to vm windows i guess.